# Sybase ASE - Tracing queries / processes

Tags: rdbms, trace, sap-ase

If there are any Sybase ASE experts out there, I was wondering if there is a way to get Sybase to trace all the queries that it receives.

I currently have a program running that usually begins displaying some strange behaviour after 7 hours from startup. I would like to find out what Sybase is doing at this time, so that I may fix the problem.

I am using Sybase ASE 15.5. And my monitoring server will not start up, for some weird reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways to *trace* all queries that Sybase receives.

However, given the second part of your question, as I understand it, you need to (1) understand what *your* query is doing (2) monitor *your* active spid in the context of other active spids and ... if that does not suffice, then (3) monitor the server; not *trace*, and *all* queries.  Therefore I will go into that and defer responding re the tracing elements available in Sybase.

Your connection to ASE is a Server Process Id, or spid.

1. SET SHOWPLAN ON and SET NOEXEC ON, and
   execute your query.  This will give
   you a very good insight into what
   your SQL is actually doing, under
   the covers.  This is an essential
   requirement, something every
   developer should be familiar with,
   and demanded before testing.  Whenever it feels like your query is slow, always check the I/O being performed: SET STATISTICS IO ON.
2. sp_who; sp_lock; and watch your spid
   ticking over, hung, waiting for
   locks, blocked, which other spids are holding it up, etc.  This is the
   basic set that every developer
   should be using, all the time.
3. sp_sysmon monitors the (entire)
   server.  It can be used in two ways:
   as an ongoing monitoring tool, eg
   grab a full hour of stats, which is
   the basis for server configuration
   changes; and as a snapshot, eg. grab
   a 5 minute snapsot of the server
   when your process is running and
   when it is not, and examine the
   differences.  Generally this is for
   experienced DBAs, not developers, and you need sa_role.

It is all in the manuals, both online and PDF.

Seven
    hours is a very long time, so you
    must be using a cursor or similar,
    and processing single rows rather
    than sets.  Check for regular nightly batch jobs (dumps, update stats, reorgs) weighing in at the 7 hour mark; some of them hold table locks.  Of course, if the server is running on Windoze, all manner of strange things, from memory leaks upwards, is standard fare; bounce the box every week at least.

With that order of processing burden, you should keep on eye on *your* transaction log and tempdb usage.

Comment: Hi PerformanceDBA, 
Thanks for the incredibly detailed reply! I haven't had a chance to try out all of the 3 tactics you gave me, but sp_who and sp_lock were exactly what I was looking for. 
Unfortunately, it didn't help me solve my problem. It did, however, tell me that the spids in Sybase were in the recv sleep state. My program was also waiting on something from Sybase, resulting in a stalemate, and thus the "strange behavior".
If it's not too much trouble, I have one more question for you: Is there a way to trace the Sybase ASE Client? (not the DB) For now I am going to try out Ribo.

Comment: If they are stalemated, they are waiting for a resource, which can be readily identified; they will not be "recv sleep" which means sleeping, waiting to receive a packet from the client.  Check the AWAITING COMMAND column & sp_lock *at the time*.  Ribo is one method for tracing; beware the volumes of output.  The other is Auditing.  Both have a setup labour cost, but Auditing is configurable.

Comment: Yup, my processes are definitely in the "recv sleep" and "AWAITING COMMAND" states. sp_lock does not show anything related to my processes. I'm guessing my client and server end up waiting on each other, rather than an being blocked by an actual lock. If there is no tracing on the ASE client, then I will have to monitor what my program sends to the client, and the SQL my client sends out to the server. I will give Auditing a try, as it sounds like it doesn't use a man-in-the-middle approach. I didn't know it was configurable, so thanks for that info :)

Comment: I posted this as a total newbie, and now I feel a lot better about maneuvering around Sybase. Thanks for all your help PerformanceDBA!

Comment: Ribo may be easier for you then.  The server (connection, spid) is always in a state of "waiting" for commands from the client, except when active (then you will see states change; pio and cpu increasing; etc).  So the job is hung on the client side at 7pm (my 2nd last para above).  hang around and do some furious checking from 6:45 onwards.  That end is easier to check without the labour reqd for Ribo.  Don't forget to vote.